# Do row locks affect both master and slave in postgreSQL

Tags: database, laravel, postgresql, load-balancing

I have searched for weeks and cant find an answer to this, so I have decided to ask.

I noticed a strange behavior on my website (technolgies: laravel and pgSLQ). I use a Master-Slave amazon RDS setup. Laravel was setup to send read queries to the slave node and write queries are sent to the master node. Unfortunately, when a row lock (lockforupdate) is performed, it appears that other threads are capable of reading the row. This behavior disappears when I return to the single server setup (meaning the lock works). I also doubt its an issue with laravel because this is not a problem on a second laravel site running on MySQL also with the same read/write architecture. So my questions I believe are:

1. How exactly are row-locks handled in master-slave pgsql setup?
2. Has anyone experienced something similar?
3. Any possibility this is an AWS RDS thing?
4. Any advice on how to handle replications in pgSQL to avoid a situation like this?

Comment: I don't quite understand. A row lock *never* prevents concurrent reading of the row. Is there a confusion in terminology?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe depends on the vendor. MySQL does block read on Select FOR UPDATE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: @veritas Yes, but the question is about a fork of PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Amazon documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html#USER_ReadRepl.PostgreSQL):

> This Read Replica (a "standby" in PostgreSQL terms) DB instance is an
>   **asynchronously** created physical replication of the master DB instance.
>   It's created by a special connection that transmits write ahead log
>   (WAL) data between the source DB instance and the Read Replica where
>   PostgreSQL asynchronously streams database changes as they are made.

(Emphasis mine)

And:

> A PostgreSQL Read Replica reports a replication lag of up to five
>   minutes if there are no user transactions occurring on the source DB
>   instance.

These Read Replica's aren't going to have the row locks of the current transaction. This is great for a lot of use cases (a reporting system, say), but apparently not for yours.

The simplest solution would be to point the queries that require the locks be pointed at the master. I don't have experience, if the feature is even available, of synchronously replicated Postgres on RDS.

Also from the [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/hot-standby.html):

> Running the same query nearly simultaneously on both primary and
>   standby might therefore return differing results. We say that data on
>   the standby is eventually consistent with the primary.

Comment: Thanks Josh, your solution makes a lot of sense. I can see Laravel supports specifying the the db connections to be used for a query - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#using-multiple-database-connections. Will implement that. Thanks again.

Comment: @FemiNefa glad to hear your problem is on the road to being solved!